# How to get source corresponding to a Python AST node?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

Python AST nodes have `lineno` and `col_offset` attributes, which indicate the beginning of respective code range. Is there an easy way to get also the end of the code range? A 3rd party library?

Comment: I also need a way to annotate nodes with end-offset info (like your solution), with python2 support as well. I am thinking of creating a standalone module that does it. Would that be of interest? @Aivar, are you happy with your approach?

Comment: @DS I'm not happy with my solution, because it's currently incomplete and occasionally some bugs come up. But I don't see other good solution. One alternative would be writing a new parser which collects more information, but I'm not ready to do this myself.

A separate package would be really nice -- there are several projects which could benefit from it. See eg this guys idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40639652/tracing-python-expression-evaluation-step-by-step

Comment: I am trying an approach which seems promising so far, which ties each node to the tokens (from tokenize module). Could you share some examples that cause trouble?

Comment: @DS. Some problem cases are here: https://bitbucket.org/plas/thonny/issues?component=ast+analysis

Comment: OK, I have a library! @Aviar, your test cases were super-helpful. It feels pretty robust now.

Comment: It's here https://github.com/gristlabs/asttokens, but I also added, with an example, as a separate answer.

Comment: Marking duplicate as it has more recent Answers [convert AST node to python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40029973/convert-ast-node-to-python-code)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We had a similar need, and I created the [asttokens](https://github.com/gristlabs/asttokens) library for this purpose. It maintains the source in both text and tokenized form, and marks AST nodes with token information, from which text is also readily available.

It works with Python 2 and 3 (tested with 2.7 and 3.5). For example:

```
import ast, asttokens
st='''
def greet(a):
  say("hello") if a else say("bye")
'''
atok = asttokens.ASTTokens(st, parse=True)
for node in ast.walk(atok.tree):
  if hasattr(node, 'lineno'):
    print atok.get_text_range(node), node.__class__.__name__, atok.get_text(node)
```

Prints

```
(1, 50) FunctionDef def greet(a):
  say("hello") if a else say("bye")
(17, 50) Expr say("hello") if a else say("bye")
(11, 12) Name a
(17, 50) IfExp say("hello") if a else say("bye")
(33, 34) Name a
(17, 29) Call say("hello")
(40, 50) Call say("bye")
(17, 20) Name say
(21, 28) Str "hello"
(40, 43) Name say
(44, 49) Str "bye"
```

Comment: A Quick and easy installation. This is a really great library.

Answer (score 15):

*EDIT: Latest code (tested in Python 3.5-3.7) is here: https://bitbucket.org/plas/thonny/src/master/thonny/ast_utils.py*

As I didn't find an easy way, here's a hard (and probably not optimal) way. Might crash and/or work incorrectly if there are more lineno/col_offset bugs in Python parser than those mentioned (and worked around) in the code. Tested in Python 3.3:

```
def mark_code_ranges(node, source):
    """
    Node is an AST, source is corresponding source as string.
    Function adds recursively attributes end_lineno and end_col_offset to each node
    which has attributes lineno and col_offset.
    """

    NON_VALUE_KEYWORDS = set(keyword.kwlist) - {'False', 'True', 'None'}


    def _get_ordered_child_nodes(node):
        if isinstance(node, ast.Dict):
            children = []
            for i in range(len(node.keys)):
                children.append(node.keys[i])
                children.append(node.values[i])
            return children
        elif isinstance(node, ast.Call):
            children = [node.func] + node.args

            for kw in node.keywords:
                children.append(kw.value)

            if node.starargs != None:
                children.append(node.starargs)
            if node.kwargs != None:
                children.append(node.kwargs)

            children.sort(key=lambda x: (x.lineno, x.col_offset))
            return children
        else:
            return ast.iter_child_nodes(node)    

    def _fix_triple_quote_positions(root, all_tokens):
        """
        http://bugs.python.org/issue18370
        """
        string_tokens = list(filter(lambda tok: tok.type == token.STRING, all_tokens))

        def _fix_str_nodes(node):
            if isinstance(node, ast.Str):
                tok = string_tokens.pop(0)
                node.lineno, node.col_offset = tok.start

            for child in _get_ordered_child_nodes(node):
                _fix_str_nodes(child)

        _fix_str_nodes(root)

        # fix their erroneous Expr parents   
        for node in ast.walk(root):
            if ((isinstance(node, ast.Expr) or isinstance(node, ast.Attribute))
                and isinstance(node.value, ast.Str)):
                node.lineno, node.col_offset = node.value.lineno, node.value.col_offset

    def _fix_binop_positions(node):
        """
        http://bugs.python.org/issue18374
        """
        for child in ast.iter_child_nodes(node):
            _fix_binop_positions(child)

        if isinstance(node, ast.BinOp):
            node.lineno = node.left.lineno
            node.col_offset = node.left.col_offset


    def _extract_tokens(tokens, lineno, col_offset, end_lineno, end_col_offset):
        return list(filter((lambda tok: tok.start[0] >= lineno
                                   and (tok.start[1] >= col_offset or tok.start[0] > lineno)
                                   and tok.end[0] <= end_lineno
                                   and (tok.end[1] <= end_col_offset or tok.end[0] < end_lineno)
                                   and tok.string != ''),
                           tokens))



    def _mark_code_ranges_rec(node, tokens, prelim_end_lineno, prelim_end_col_offset):
        """
        Returns the earliest starting position found in given tree, 
        this is convenient for internal handling of the siblings
        """

        # set end markers to this node
        if "lineno" in node._attributes and "col_offset" in node._attributes:
            tokens = _extract_tokens(tokens, node.lineno, node.col_offset, prelim_end_lineno, prelim_end_col_offset)
            #tokens = 
            _set_real_end(node, tokens, prelim_end_lineno, prelim_end_col_offset)

        # mark its children, starting from last one
        # NB! need to sort children because eg. in dict literal all keys come first and then all values
        children = list(_get_ordered_child_nodes(node))
        for child in reversed(children):
            (prelim_end_lineno, prelim_end_col_offset) = \
                _mark_code_ranges_rec(child, tokens, prelim_end_lineno, prelim_end_col_offset)

        if "lineno" in node._attributes and "col_offset" in node._attributes:
            # new "front" is beginning of this node
            prelim_end_lineno = node.lineno
            prelim_end_col_offset = node.col_offset

        return (prelim_end_lineno, prelim_end_col_offset)

    def _strip_trailing_junk_from_expressions(tokens):
        while (tokens[-1].type not in (token.RBRACE, token.RPAR, token.RSQB,
                                      token.NAME, token.NUMBER, token.STRING, 
                                      token.ELLIPSIS)
                    and tokens[-1].string not in ")}]"
                    or tokens[-1].string in NON_VALUE_KEYWORDS):
            del tokens[-1]

    def _strip_trailing_extra_closers(tokens, remove_naked_comma):
        level = 0
        for i in range(len(tokens)):
            if tokens[i].string in "({[":
                level += 1
            elif tokens[i].string in ")}]":
                level -= 1

            if level == 0 and tokens[i].string == "," and remove_naked_comma:
                tokens[:] = tokens[0:i]
                return

            if level < 0:
                tokens[:] = tokens[0:i]
                return   

    def _set_real_end(node, tokens, prelim_end_lineno, prelim_end_col_offset):
        # prelim_end_lineno and prelim_end_col_offset are the start of 
        # next positioned node or end of source, ie. the suffix of given
        # range may contain keywords, commas and other stuff not belonging to current node

        # Function returns the list of tokens which cover all its children


        if isinstance(node, _ast.stmt):
            # remove empty trailing lines
            while (tokens[-1].type in (tokenize.NL, tokenize.COMMENT, token.NEWLINE, token.INDENT)
                   or tokens[-1].string in (":", "else", "elif", "finally", "except")):
                del tokens[-1]

        else:
            _strip_trailing_extra_closers(tokens, not isinstance(node, ast.Tuple))
            _strip_trailing_junk_from_expressions(tokens)

        # set the end markers of this node
        node.end_lineno = tokens[-1].end[0]
        node.end_col_offset = tokens[-1].end[1]

        # Try to peel off more tokens to give better estimate for children
        # Empty parens would confuse the children of no argument Call
        if ((isinstance(node, ast.Call)) 
            and not (node.args or node.keywords or node.starargs or node.kwargs)):
            assert tokens[-1].string == ')'
            del tokens[-1]
            _strip_trailing_junk_from_expressions(tokens)
        # attribute name would confuse the "value" of Attribute
        elif isinstance(node, ast.Attribute):
            if tokens[-1].type == token.NAME:
                del tokens[-1]
                _strip_trailing_junk_from_expressions(tokens)
            else:
                raise AssertionError("Expected token.NAME, got " + str(tokens[-1]))
                #import sys
                #print("Expected token.NAME, got " + str(tokens[-1]), file=sys.stderr)

        return tokens

    all_tokens = list(tokenize.tokenize(io.BytesIO(source.encode('utf-8')).readline))
    _fix_triple_quote_positions(node, all_tokens)
    _fix_binop_positions(node)
    source_lines = source.split("\n") 
    prelim_end_lineno = len(source_lines)
    prelim_end_col_offset = len(source_lines[len(source_lines)-1])
    _mark_code_ranges_rec(node, all_tokens, prelim_end_lineno, prelim_end_col_offset)
```

Comment: I understand nothing but I upvote for the work and the sharing of work.

Comment: It turned out more complex actually. New code is here: https://bitbucket.org/plas/thonny/src (look for ast_utils.py in the package called "thonny")

Answer (score 11):

`ast.get_source_segment` was added in python 3.8:

```
import ast

code = """
if 1 == 1 and 2 == 2 and 3 == 3:
     test = 1
"""
node = ast.parse(code)
ast.get_source_segment(code, node.body[0])
```

Produces: `if 1 == 1 and 2 == 2 and 3 == 3:\n     test = 1`

Thanks to [Blane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3163667/blane) for his answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62624882/3800552

Answer (score 1):

Hi I know its very late , But I think is this is what you are looking for,
I am doing the parsing only for  function definitions in the module.
We can get the first and last line of the ast node by this method. This way the source code lines of a function definition can be obtained by parsing the source file by reading only the lines we need . 
This is a very simple example ,

```
st='def foo():\n    print "hello" \n\ndef bla():\n    a = 1\n    b = 2\n  
c= a+b\n    print c'

import ast 
tree = ast.parse(st)
for function in tree.body:
    if isinstance(function,ast.FunctionDef):
        # Just in case if there are loops in the definition
        lastBody = func.body[-1]
        while isinstance (lastBody,(ast.For,ast.While,ast.If)):
            lastBody = lastBody.Body[-1]
        lastLine = lastBody.lineno
        print "Name of the function is ",function.name
        print "firstLine of the function is ",function.lineno
        print "LastLine of the function is ",lastLine
        print "the source lines are "
        if isinstance(st,str):
            st = st.split("\n")
        for i , line in enumerate(st,1):
            if i in range(function.lineno,lastLine+1):
                print line
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it doesn't help me. I need locations for all nodes and not only line numbers but also columns.

Comment: oh I am really sorry then. I will look for it and keep you posted.

Comment: That's right! I want to highlight the corresponding code range when an arbitrary expression or statement node is selected in the AST

Comment: i think you only need the first and last line of the node. I am also doing something similar. please check my edit to the answer if that helps you in anyway.