# convert AST node to python code

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

Suppose I have the following string:

```
code = """
if 1 == 1 and 2 == 2 and 3 == 3:
    test = 1
"""
```

The following code converts that string in a AST.

```
ast.parse(code)
```

Then I have a tree like:

```
Module(body=[<_ast.If object at 0x100747358>])
  If(test=BoolOp(op=And(), values=[<_ast.Compare object at 0x100747438>, <_ast.Compare object at 0x100747a90>, <_ast.Compare object at 0x100747d68>]), body=[<_ast.Assign object at 0x100747e48>], orelse=[])
```

I want to know if there is a way to convert the object `at.If` into the string `if 1 == 1 and 2 == 2 and 3 == 3:`

I know it can be done traversing the children node, but it's getting too complicated that way.

Comment: `traversing the children node,` <- that's the only way I know how to do it

Comment: There are 3rd party tools that make a credible attempt, e.g. [`astor`](http://astor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [astunparse](https://astunparse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library which was basically just code from the core, repackaged individually.

First, install the library:

```
pip install astunparse
```

Then, run your AST module through it to get the source right back. So running:

```
import ast
import astunparse

code = """
if 1 == 1 and 2 == 2 and 3 == 3:
    test = 1
"""

node = ast.parse(code)

astunparse.unparse(node)
```

Will output:

```
'\nif ((1 == 1) and (2 == 2) and (3 == 3)):\n    test = 1\n'
```

Answer (score 16):

Python 3.9 introduced [ast.unparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.unparse) which does exactly this, i.e. it reverses `ast.parse`. Using your example:

```py
import ast

code = """
if 1 == 1 and 2 == 2 and 3 == 3:
    test = 1
"""

tree = ast.parse(code)
print(ast.unparse(tree))
```

This will print out:

```
if 1 == 1 and 2 == 2 and (3 == 3):
    test = 1
```

Note that there may be slight differences to the original input.

Answer (score 12):

`ast.get_source_segment` was added in python 3.8:

```py
>>> import ast

>>> code = """
>>> if 1 == 1 and 2 == 2 and 3 == 3:
>>>     test = 1
>>> """
>>> node = ast.parse(code)
>>> ast.get_source_segment(code, node.body[0])
'if 1 == 1 and 2 == 2 and 3 == 3:\n    test = 1'
```