# How do I force import class from other file, when this file has another class dependent on missing module?

Tags: python

`main.py`

```
from plugin import UsefulClass

worker = UsefulClass()
worker.do_your_job()
```

`plugin.py`

```
import missing_module

class MyPlugin(missing_module.Plugin):
  def something(self):
    print('blabla')

class UsefulClass:
  def do_your_job(self):
    print('done')
```

In `main.py` I want to import `UsefulClass` from `plugin.py`. However, `plugin.py` is missing dependency for other class `MyPlugin`.

`UsefulClass` doesn't have dependencies on `MyPlugin` class.

Is there a way to force Python import `UsefulClass` and ignore ImportError?
I want to keep `plugin.py` self contained without splitting it into 2 files.

Comment: [`fuckit`](https://github.com/ajalt/fuckitpy), maybe?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer I wrote for a related problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45684307/get-source-script-details-similar-to-inspect-getmembers-without-importing-the/45684477#45684477). TL;DR: It monkeypatches the `__import__` function so that `import missing_module` doesn't throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the missing module ahead of time, you could write a replacement module that contains a dummy version of the missing class and save it in the same directory as your main script (or in another directory in `sys.path`).

```
# missing_module.py
class Plugin:
    pass
```

The `import` in `plugin.py` should then pick up that module and be satisfied. Obviously, `MyPlugin` won't work.